# Arrays in visual basic (Related to program that deals with driving distance)

Tags: vb.net

I have an assignment where we must create a project that looks up the driving distance between two cities.

> Use two drop-down lists that contain the names of the cities. Label one list “Departure” and the other “Destination”. Use a Look Up button to calculate the distance. Store the distances in a two-dimensional table.

I started doing it, but I noticed I would be having to repeat the code too many times and I know there is a better way to do it. That's where I need help.

Is there a way to use a For loop in this problem and if so, how would I do it?

```
Option Strict On
Public Class Form1


Dim Distance(,) As Long = {{0, 1004, 1753, 2752, 3017, 1520, 1507, 609, 3155, 448},
                           {1004, 0, 921, 1780, 2048, 1397, 919, 515, 2176, 709},
                           {1753, 921, 0, 1230, 1399, 1343, 517, 1435, 2234, 1307},
                           {2752, 1780, 1230, 0, 272, 2570, 1732, 2251, 1322, 2420},
                           {3017, 2048, 1399, 272, 0, 2716, 1858, 2523, 1278, 2646},
                           {1520, 1397, 1343, 2570, 2716, 0, 860, 1494, 3447, 1057},
                           {1507, 919, 517, 1732, 1858, 860, 0, 1307, 2734, 1099},
                           {609, 515, 1435, 2251, 2523, 1494, 1307, 0, 2820, 571},
                           {3155, 2176, 2234, 1322, 1278, 3447, 2734, 2820, 0, 2887},
                           {448, 709, 1307, 2420, 2646, 1057, 1099, 571, 2887, 0}}

Private Sub LookUpBtn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles LookUpBtn.Click

        If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0 And ComboBox2.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
            DistanceLbl.Text = (Distance(0, 0).ToString & " miles")
        ElseIf ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0 And ComboBox2.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
            DistanceLbl.Text = (Distance(0, 1).ToString & " miles")
        ElseIf ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0 And ComboBox2.SelectedIndex = 2 Then
            DistanceLbl.Text = (Distance(0, 2).ToString & " miles")
        ElseIf ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0 And ComboBox2.SelectedIndex = 3 Then
            DistanceLbl.Text = (Distance(0, 3).ToString & " miles")
        ElseIf ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0 And ComboBox2.SelectedIndex = 4 Then
            DistanceLbl.Text = (Distance(0, 4).ToString & " miles")
        ElseIf ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0 And ComboBox2.SelectedIndex = 5 Then
            DistanceLbl.Text = (Distance(0, 5).ToString & " miles")
        ElseIf ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0 And ComboBox2.SelectedIndex = 6 Then
            DistanceLbl.Text = (Distance(0, 6).ToString & " miles")
        ElseIf ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0 And ComboBox2.SelectedIndex = 7 Then
            DistanceLbl.Text = (Distance(0, 7).ToString & " miles")
        ElseIf ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0 And ComboBox2.SelectedIndex = 8 Then
            DistanceLbl.Text = (Distance(0, 8).ToString & " miles")
        ElseIf ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0 And ComboBox2.SelectedIndex = 9 Then
            DistanceLbl.Text = (Distance(0, 9).ToString & " miles")
        End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's good that you noticed the repetition and thought about For loops, but you don't actually need one for this problem.

You're doing the equivalent of:

- if x=0 and y=0 then look at array(0,0)
- if x=0 and y=1 then look at array(0,1)
- ...
- if x=9 and y=9 then look at array(9,9)

Which can be expressed much more simply as:

- look at array(x,y)

Therefore, for your real code, it's as simple as this:

```
DistanceLbl.Text = (Distance(
    ComboBox1.SelectedIndex, 
    ComboBox2.SelectedIndex).ToString & " miles")
```

Answer (score 2):

Use directly the `SelectedIndex` as offset for you array :

```
Distance(ComboBox1.SelectedIndex, ComboBox2.SelectedIndex)
```

You will probably need a test for the case "none selected" where SelectedIndex is -1 and trying to access that offset in the array will get an ArgumentOutOfRangeException.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you simply need to use the values from the combobox when accessing the array.  This can replace the entire If..Elseif part of your code.

```
DistanceLbl.Text = (Distance(ComboBox1.SelectedIndex, ComboBox2.SelectedIndex).ToString & " miles")
```